Routing in Altium Designer
During routing I faced a very strange issue, when I want to connect my routing to a resistor pin with the same net name, Altium does not allow me to do so:

Would you please let me know what can be the reason? and how to fix it?

This link will take you, even without a valid license, to an excellent (and official) Altium forum: https://forum.live.altium.com (where all you need to do is register for an account).

@ChrisKnudsen I agree that the forum would be better, We do allow software questions here

@VoltageSpike I'm not saying that it is not allowed.  I am saying that the Altium forum is a better source for quick, high quality answers.  It is the best, free, source for the Altium masses.

@ChrisKnudsen That's fine also

Try and create two more of the same part that are linked together in the schematic and import them into the PCB, if you still have the same issue, then it may be that there is a problem with the footprint (like something weird with the pins or some kind of weird keepout region in the footprint.
If that works and you have no issues connecting to it after it's copied then it could be an issue with the net or some kind of naming issue.
The last thing is checking your DRC and seeing if there are any clearance rules preventing you from connecting to that pin.
Also try routing the trace out from the device/pin and see if the net name is the same
